# How to Deploy Different App Settings for different Environments on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appsettings, web.config-transform

I want to run **different app settings on different environments** using Microsoft Azure in visual studio 2015.

for Local Environment:

```
<add key="EnvironmentPath" value="http://local:12345" />
```

for QA:

```
<add key="EnvironmentPath" value="http://qa.abc.com" />
```

for staging:

```
 <add key="EnvironmentPath" value="http://staging.abc.com" />
```

And it automatically load its specific value in each environment.
like in HTML Template

```
<a href="appsettings["EnvironmentPath"]"></a>
```

Any help.

Comment: Did you push your code to azure using continous integration ?

Comment: No I Pushed it from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your web.config, if you are publishing manually you need to change the **Solution Configuration** before publishing it.

Based on the Microsoft documentation:

> 1. If you want to create a transform file for a custom build configuration that does not exist, create the build configuration
>      first by using Configuration Manager.
>
> You can open Configuration Manager by selecting it from the Build
>   menu. For more information, see Configuration Manager Dialog Box.
>
> 2. In Solution Explorer, expand the application Web.config file.
>
> If any transform files have already been created, the Web.config file
>   is displayed in Solution Explorer with a symbol indicating that it can
>   be expanded, and the transform files are shown when you expand the
>   Web.config file.
>
> The build configuration that a transform is for is indicated by a
>   string in the file name. For example, a transform file for the Debug
>   build configuration is named Web.Debug.config.
>
> 3. If no transform file exists for the build configuration that you want to specify settings for, in Solution Explorer, right-click the
>      Web.config file and then click Add Config Transforms.
> 4. Open the transform file for the build configuration that you want to work with.
> 5. Edit the transform file to specify the changes that should be made to the deployed Web.config file when you deploy by using that build
>      configuration.
>
> The default transform file includes comments that show how to code
>   some common transforms.
>
> The following example shows how to use the Match locator and the
>   SetAttributes transform attribute. The Match locator attribute
>   identifies the add element in the connectionStrings section as the
>   element to change. The SetAttributes transform attribute specifies
>   that this element's connectionString attribute should be changed to
>   "ReleaseSQLServer".

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="ReleaseSQLServer" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

> 6. Save and close the transform file.
>
> When you deploy the Web application by using the selected build
>   configuration and by using either a deployment package or one-click
>   publish, the Web.config file is transformed according to your
>   specifications.

Comment: Do you mean app.config ? if so, you can install a nuget package that does it for you. I use SlowCheetah: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/